# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer un array multinivel dinamicamente? (array de árbol) php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito construir un array en base a una consulta a la base de datos. El caso es que hay datos que pueden ser hijos de otros y estos a su vez hijos de otros, lo que quiero construir es un array para poder construir lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me haga entender y puedan ayudarme..

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask], ayudaría mucho agregues un ejemplo en código de lo que llevas al momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo creando una funcion que se llame a si misma si en el array encuentra hijos, es decir, otro array :)

```
    function iterateRecursive(&$directory)
    {
        foreach ($directory as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value)) {
              iterateRecursive($value); //iterar una y otra vez si hay hijos
            }

             echo $value; // Mostrar el valor padre  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, al final decidí realizar un procedimiento almacenado que me retornara lo que requería, pero tu solución también es muy viable